# Using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a graphical representation of table relations using "Mysql workbench".

I double clicked on "MySQL Model" tab and added Diagram.

But I can not figure out how to display the tables from current DB. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "current DB."

If you mean existing tables in "the current MySQL Workbench model," then make sure the "Catalog" window is visible (View=>Windows=>Catalog) and you can drag and drop tables onto the canvas.

If you mean you want to reverse engineer your existing database, then you can do so as follows:

On the "Database" menu, there is a "Reverse Engineer" wizard.  It will let you connect to a MySQL server and reverse engineer schemata.  Then you can create diagrams from those database objects.  You can also use the "Forward Engineer" wizard, which generates and executes SQL DDL statements based on your diagrams.

Comment: >> On the "Database" menu, there is a "Reverse Engineer" wizard. It will let you connect to a MySQL server and reverse engineer schemata.

Thank you very much. I wasted several hours but could not figure it out!

Comment: Is there any way I can appreciate the answer? 
I have clicked on the up arrow and accepted the answer by clicking on the correct sign. But I guess that is not enough for saving a few hours trying to figure out that was so easy to achieve.